# jRAT virus on Linux

Tags: linux, virus, java

I dumbly downloaded a .jar file that contained jRAT.
When run, it stalls, gives a FileNotFoundException, then crashes. When I ls'd, the jar was there. When I cd'd out and back in, the jar was gone.

I'm running Debian Wheezy, and GNOME. Now there is a white block thing in the panel, and when hovering over it it says jRAT.
Here's the block:

[image: white blocky thingie in panel]

Here's me hovering over it:

[image]

3 questions:

1. How do I get rid of this?
2. How did it remove itself?
3. How can I remove the annoying white blocky thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There's apparently a remover hosted by the author of jRAT at
   https://github.com/redpois0n/. I recommend reading the sources and
   cleaning up yourself rather than running untrusted code though :-)
2. No idea. It could be that it redefined your ls function, but you would normally require a reload of the environment to have the new ls taken into account. Was that thing installed as root? How exactly did you cd back in? With a new terminal? Are you sure it didn't just delete itself and your timing was just a coincidence?
3. Isn't this the same question as 1? In any case you can identify the running process, it should have a socket or a D-Bus connection (or a pipe or shm segment or any other IPC handle) open with your desktop environment's panel. Find out how your panel handles systray notifications and then figure out how to find if a process uses the systray. Then you can happily parse /proc to find the culprits! (and some possible alternative methods on [this SE question](https://superuser.com/questions/97844/how-can-i-determine-what-process-has-a-file-open-in-linux))

Comment: Ensure you clean .profile, .bash_rc, your XDG autostart directory, whatever files you have that define the XDG session you run (not sure where these are located).

Comment: Reply to No. 2: All in the same terminal. And it was run by me (not root).

Comment: I would go with coincidental deleting then, at least until I can get hold of some code to read.

Comment: It hid itself in my Documents folder as `.com.apple.mobilesecurity.Bonjour.jar,jar`. Tricky thing, considering that I deal with Apple stuff alot. Thank you!

Comment: I would not assume that the code "knows" you would be unlikelier to delete Bonjour than another user. Rather, Bonjour has a legitimate reason to be run on any platform. Don't you have access to the code in the jar? If you do you could (maybe?) check what else you need to clean up.

Comment: I can check the code later... But I think it was named that because it was supposed to be apple-related. (Don't trust run-me-to-unzip files!)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17880/discussion-between-awesomebing1-and-steve-dl).